# I don't know how to bring my model back after clicking a mesh data link on the object data tab

Tags: mesh

I am not even sure what to call it. The model was not created by me, but I wanted to mess with it. It came in OBJ and I went through and combined it all together. After messing in the menus I discovered this under object data. I clicked this, and now the rest of the mesh is gone, and I don't know how to bring it back.

[image: This is my problem.]

Comment: 1.Have you tried to search it in the outliner, and change x,y,z loc to 0? 2. If it appear in the outliner, select it and clic on Object (right to Add) => Transform => Origin to Geometry. After this, try again the step 1.

Comment: Everything is already at the correct origin, and zeroed out (I think). The problem I have is as seen in the image I can only view one part of the mesh at a time. When I loaded it initially I could view the whole thing I don't understand what I did.

Comment: I don't think that is helping hack0re. I figured out what its called its called "Linked mesh data". Still don't know what to do with it =/

Comment: Maybe you can share the blend, someone can try to fix it.

Comment: Okay I figured it out. All those different mesh data links where links from the original mesh I placed on the second layer for safe guarding. I deleted the original mesh, and was left with only the options I wanted and my original mesh reappeared.

Comment: A blender mesh object has mesh data associated with it, basically the vertices, edges and faces.  What you are seeing in the menu is the name of each  individual OBJ mesh you originally imported. Changing it makes it the mesh of the context object (the one selected)  One of these will be your joined mesh.  As a scripter I would write a simple loop to get the mesh with the most faces to find it, not sure how to do it otherwise without brute force trying each.

Comment: Took too long to type that one lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the OBJ mesh I imported had several "parts". What I did was when I went into object data I was viewing the old parts from the original mesh I imported. So I deleted the original mesh with so many "parts". Afterwards the only things I seen in mesh data were my object, and my floor plane. I selected my object, and it reappeared.